# Waiting for external js file in child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a parent component that's loading an external js file dynamically(Like what is described   [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch)).

and the child component take the variable inside the js file.  but every time i load the page, the child component throws an error because child component rendered before external js file loaded.  How can I avoid this?

```
      //in parent component
      app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        created() {
            this.loadJsFile('assets/js/extra.js')
        },
        methods: {
            
            loadJsFile(src) {
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = src;

                let head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
                head.appendChild(script);
            },
```

in extra.js:

```
var extra = { users:[{id:1, name:'foo'}], images:[...] }
```

child component:

```
  data() {
    return {
        users:[],
     }
},

created(){
     this.users = extra.users
   },
```

cause the error:

```
 [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: extra is not defined"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options in your case:

### 1. Insert the `<script>` tag programatically

parent component:

```js
<ChildComponent :extra="users"></ChildComponent>

...
mounted() {
  this.loadJsFile('assets/js/extra.js').then(() => {
    if (window.extra) {
      this.users = extra.users
    }
  })
}

// ...

loadJsFile(src) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.onload = () => {
      resolve();
    };
    script.onerror = () => {
      reject();
    };
    script.src = src;

    let head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.appendChild(script);
  });
}
```

child component:

```js
...
   props: {
      extra: Array
    },
   data() {
    return {
        users:[],
     }
   },
   created(){
     this.users = this.extra.users
   },
```

### 2. Add `<script>` tag to `index.html` file:

Just add the `<script src="static/js/extra.js"></script>` to the end of the `index.html` file and then you can access the `extra` variable globally.

Comment: The problem is when to tell to the child to use the variable extra. child component renders before loading external js file

Comment: The `users` is in child component you can't access by: this.users

Comment: ok, this is my mistake. I will update the next answer and but you can pass `extra` to child component through `props`, or notify child components via call `emit`.

Comment: the benefit of State Management is that you can use it every where, i' m using external js file as a source of truth,

Comment: please take a look at : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch

Comment: So are you using vuex?

Comment: no, a Simple State Management, an external js file as a state

Comment: I've updated the answer, please try to implement this :)